# When starting up mumble, or teamspeak, and it goes to record audio (for say voice chat) all playback is held up

Tags: linux, fedora, audio

On Fedora 17. Using a ct-xfi driver. I have my speakers configured, and everything works great.

Until I start up mumble, or Teamspeak, and either one hooks up to start recording audio. Then it's all over. All sound playback stops, and seems like it's in a huge buffer.

A few moments after quitting mumble, or Teamspeak, all sound catches back up, or is released.

I cannot find anything on the Google about this particular problem, and fiddling with various sound settings and input/output drivers within mumble or teamspeak has absolutely no effect.

Thanks for any help, I'll be around to provide more information of course.

**EDIT:** Fedora 17 KDE uses Pulseaudio, and so I'm using Pulseaudio.

Comment: What is your Audioserver? Pulsaudio? ALSA?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like mumble and TS are blocking the soundcard. You should check that mumble uses Pulsaudio as soundserver and not OSS. Look under Settings and make sure that Adveanced is ticked.

Comment: Yeah, they're both using PulseAudio, I've gone through all the various audio backends to no luck.

Comment: Of course, I fire it up again, and everything just works. Perhaps there was a horrible glitch in the packages :(

Comment: This doesn't work again :( Seems to block all output.